# PHP Function Strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I am passing a date in "Y-m-d H:i" format to strtotime and it is returning 5hours 30 minutes less in result.

Comment: Is the PHP timezone set correctly? You can probably see it using the phpinfo() function.

Comment: Seeing as you're probably from Asia (e.g. India, which IIRC is GMT +5:30), it's probably a time zone issue. Please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the timezone correctly. You can use `date_default_timezone_set()` to set it to what you want.